# Add columns from another dataframe based on common values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different dataframes.

| product_ID | product_score | product_number_reviews | user_ID | user_review_recommended |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 78 | 105 | 45840 | True |
| 7302 | 65.0 | 3510 | 4871 | True |
| 7302 | 65.0 | 3510 | 1251 | False |
| 7302 | 65.0 | 3510 | 125 | True |
| 154 | 57 | 51 | 8525 | True |
| 18 | 28 | 8 | 8525 | False |

and

| product_ID | product_type | product_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | Toy | 59.99 |
| 7302 | Beauty | 39.99 |
| 154 | Movie | 19.99 |
| 10 | Grocery | 6.99 |
| 18 | Toy | 12.99 |

And I would like to add the columns of the second dataframe (product_type & product_price) that are missing in the first one, using product_ID as common values. The problem is that they do not have the same number of rows, and that products that exists in the second dataframe (like the product_ID = 10) that might not exist in the first dataframe.

So, this is what I want to get:

| product_ID | product_score | product_number_reviews | user_ID | user_review_recommended | product_type | product_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 78 | 105 | 45840 | True | Toy | 59.99 |
| 7302 | 65.0 | 3510 | 4871 | True | Beauty | 39.99 |
| 7302 | 65.0 | 3510 | 1251 | False | Beauty | 39.99 |
| 7302 | 65.0 | 3510 | 125 | True | Beauty | 39.99 |
| 154 | 65.0 | 3510 | 8525 | True | Movie | 19.99 |
| 18 | 28 | 8 | 821 | False | Toy | 12.99 |

I tried to do :

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="product_ID", how="left")
```

It works, but I get NaN in product_type and product_price for the last rows. I suppose it is because they do not share the same number of rows, and that it is only working for the number of rows that are common in both dataframes.

Can you help me on that matter? Thank you.

Comment: The code you propose works for me. The two dataframes don't have to share the same number of rows. `NaNs` appear when a corresponding value has not been found in the second dataset. Maybe there is a mistake in your column `product_ID` (a whitespace for instance)

Comment: Yes, for some reason, it just worked after I restarted my computer. I don't know what caused that, but I'm glad it is working now aha!

Comment: You probably modified a view of the DataFrames. Make sure that if you want to create another and independent DataFrame based on a DataFrame in memory you use `df2 = df1.copy()` instead of `df2 = df1`. In the latter case whatever you do to df2 will also be applied to df, which is likely not what you want.